# Error in writing splashscreen code with timer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, splash-screen

So I'm writing an app in Android Studio and I am a begginer. So, there's an error causing other errors in my code for splashscreen with timer. I really tried to fix it but I just can't figure it out.And sorry if this was already written somewhere, I'm also new at stackoverflow so I don't really get it all.Thanks for help.
This is error image link->https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5FN2.jpg

This is the code

```
package com.example.shromid;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT=4000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent homeIntent=new Intent(SplashScreen.class,MainActivity.this);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
            finish();
        }
            }SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent homeIntent=new Intent(SplashScreen.class,MainActivity.this);
        startActivity(homeIntent);
        finish();
    }
}, SPLASH_TIME_OUT); // See the comma?
```

You are missing the comment between the end of the definition of the anonymous `Runnable` and the second argument which is the handler delay.

Comment: Thank you,that was the solution, I was putting and dot instead of comma.